# How to unlock system keychain in OS X using terminal

Tags: ios, shell, jenkins, keychain, codesign

I have private key and certificate in system keychain and I want to access it using *CodeSign* so it needs to be unlocked.

if I try to unlock login keychain using below script then no problem

```
security unlock-keychain -p password login.keychain
```

But If I use the same syntax for system.keychain then I get this error *security: SecKeychainUnlock The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.*

```
security unlock-keychain -p password /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

From this what I can see there is no way to enter username in the syntax.

My intention is to *unlock the keychain* while *code-signing* the build,so that I won't get prompt like below.In the case of code-signing event in jenkins I'd get error like "*User Interaction is not allowed*"

I know this problem can be solved by giving access to all apps in keychain But I intend to do it via script itself.

[image: code sign alert]

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Any reason why not to move certificate from system to login keychain?

Comment: @RoyK - I'd like to do it from system keychain itself

Comment: @RoyK - is it possible that I can create my very own keychain and move all the certificates over there and access without any username and password ?

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H did you ever find out how to do that?

Comment: @rexford - I couldn't find out and I am just keeping it unlocked manually on jenkins server

Comment: @rexford - Just now I found out that jenkins gives option to unlock keychain from its interface we just have to pass the keychain path and password.it unlocks it.If jenkins can do it then we can do it through terminal as well.

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H thanks for the feedback! Now I am really curious how Jenkins achieves this feat.

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H "I couldn't find out and I am just keeping it unlocked manually on jenkins server"  are you unlocking the system keychain? If yes, post  that is there any prompt for admin credentials?